# IS zk-SNARK not suitable for constructing anonymous authentication scheme?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, authentication, anonymity, snarks

zk-SNARK was a powerful tool for privacy-respecting e-cash. However, recent years, in the literatures about anonymous authentication scheme, such as group signatures, anonymous credential, blind signature, etc., the construction of these schemes did not use zk-SNARK as the NIZK tool, but traditional ways(Fiat-Shamir transform in ROM or CRS-based Groth-Sahai NIZK). So, my questions are:

1. If one use zk-SNARK as NIZK tool in an anonymous authentication scheme, will it lead to some effiency or secure problems? and why?
2. Can the zk-SNARK only be used in Blockchain-based privacy-preserving schemes or verifiable computation?

In other words, I wanna construct a group signatures/anonymous credential scheme by using zk-SNARK, due to its "succinct" proof. But for now I haven't found any literature about this counstruction method for group signatures/anonymous credential scheme. So the above questions are presented.

Comment: You seem to assume that using a Fiat-Shamir transformation never yields a zk-SNARK, but this is not necessarily the case I think. Maybe https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/74382/zk-snarks-vs-zk-starks-vs-bulletproofs-definitions helps you grasp a bit more. A zk-SNARK is not a specific algorithm, but a category of algorithms.  
Your questions aren't very clear to me, especially the second one: do you ask whether a zk-SNARK is something that cannot be used outside of blockchain?

Comment: @RubenDeSmet Thank you for your answers. Acutally, I wanna design a group signatures where the NIZK is very important component. So, when I learn the advantages of  zk-SNARK, I wanna use it as the NIZK argument in my construction of group signatures.  But there is no paper talked about this. Therefore, I wondered that whether the zk-SNARK can only be used in verifable computation or limited scenes?

Answer (score 1):

For now, I have gradually understood why the zk-SNARK cannot be suitable for constructing anonymous authentication scheme. That is the performance issue.

According to some references:

[1][Succinct Non-Interactive Zero Knowledge for a von Neumann Architecture](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/879.pdf);

[2][Comparing General Purpose zk-SNARKs](https://medium.com/coinmonks/comparing-general-purpose-zk-snarks-51ce124c60bd)

The zk-SNARK takes seconds to perform a proof operation. Therefore, due to the requirement of efficent computing for the prover is essential to an anonymous authentication scheme, the zk-SNARK cannot meet it.

Comment: I disagree. zk-SNARKs are actually terribly *fast*. The things you link there use extremely complex circuits, [1] for instance runs a full RISC and then *seems* slow to prove a TSP witness, but it actually has a lot of overhead because it's proving a whole Turing machine with a lot of state transitions. Proving their TSP witness shouldn't$^{\text{[citation needed]}}$ take more than a few thousand constraints at most, while their example takes ~300k multiplication gates.
That said, constructing your own ZK scheme for your specific authentication system will probably always be faster.

Comment: @RubenDeSmet A huge thanks to your response. You inspired me to continue researching zk-SNARK and update this answer.

Comment: I wish you very well in your search. I might post an answer in a few months myself, because I'm actually authoring a paper that's very much related to this topic.

Comment: @RubenDeSmet Great! I also have some ideas to build my scheme by improving the zk-SNARK, and I look forward to your answer or paper:)